# Rails sort posts by Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

After doing my due diligence online and elsewhere, I'm still having trouble sorting my posts (view and controller) based on their category.

I have three models: `Design`, `Category`, and `Type`.

Design.rb

```
belongs_to :type
```

Category.rb

```
has_many :designs
has_many :types, :order => "name"
```

Type.rb

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :design
```

If something needs to be changed here, please shed light to that.

After starting this search to find the answer to sort posts, I came across another problem that I'll ask in another question but will disclose here just in case. In the Command Line, if I search for a category, I get the category but also the warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Category.has_many :types declaration are deprecated: :order. Please use a scope block instead.
```

and when I search for a Type I get this warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using #scope without passing a callable object is deprecated. For example `scope :red, where(color: 'red')` should be changed to `scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }`.
```

Anyway, in my current app, the categories are `men` and `women` and the types include `accessories, shirts, tops, jackets, etc` and so on. When a user created a design, they have a select to choose the type that has headings like this:

```
Men
  Accessories
  Jackets
  etc
Women
  Accessories
  Dresses
  etc
```

In my view, I want the user to be able to sort the posts by men or women (Category) and also even further by `Type`, like `Women's Accessories` or `Men's Accessories`

Both Category and Type's can be found by either their ID or a string.

If I can provide anything else to help, please let me know and I'll include as much as I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 4, you pass conditions to a `has_many`, `belongs_to`, etc. in a block:

```
has_many :types, -> { order("name") }
```

Then, when the association is accessed, that block will be called on the association, e.g.:

```
my_category.types

# would return the same result as
my_category.types.order("name")
```

Comment: Thanks that helps with the deprecation warning, although I think you're supposed to add `->`... `has_many :types, -> { order("name") }`